# how to find real life distance between a camera and a pixel point (x and y coordinates) in an image captured by that camera?

Tags: c++, 3d, computer-vision, geometry, distance

So I tried to implement logic by first considering that camera is placed on ground and captured image, I first calculated distance between bottom most pixel on image along y axis and px and py coordinates on image then I translated that distance into real life by multiplying resulted value with real life distance covered in a pixel of that image. Now my task was to re calculate distance when now camera is lifted above at some height (making angle of 90 deg from ground). Now how can I re calculate distance between new camera position (i.e., at some height) and a point on image taken by that camera at new position?

```
// point of image along y-axis until ground is visible 
const int groundY = 50;
// real life distance from origin (i.e. from where camera is placed and image bottom most point along y-axis) to point where ground is visible in image 
const int realLifeGroundDist = 200;
const int cameraHeight = 40;

void geoLocation(int ***a, int x, int y, int z, int px, int py){

    double onePixelDistance = realLifeGroundDist/groundY;
    // double distBtwPixels = sqrt(pow(px - ((x/2)-1), 2) + pow(py - (y-1), 2) * 1);

    // Distance formula to calculate dist btw origin and (px,py) pixel
    double distBtwPixels = sqrt(pow(px - (x-1), 2) + pow(py - ((y/2)-1), 2) * 1);
    
    //translating pixel distance to real life distance
    double h = distBtwPixels * onePixelDistance;

    //considering that camera is placed above ground at some height i.e. cameraHeight variable at angle = 90deg and calculating distance btw that point and camera i.e. hypteneuse
    double realLifeDist = sqrt(pow(h, 2) + pow(cameraHeight, 2));
    
    cout<<"Distance between camera and px and py coordinates in image = "<<realLifeDist;
}
```

According to my logic realLifeDist holds distance between point on image captured by camera placed on new location i.e. at some height from ground making angle of 90 deg from ground. Is my logic correct? If not, then how can I calculate it?

Comment: This seems like a math question rather than a programming question. Consider asking at https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Since your view frustum is generally a pyramid, the realLifeDist for a given dstBtwPixels depends on the distance from the camera. If that distance can change in your scenario, the realLifeDist cannot be calculated.

Comment: do you have depth information? a pixel on an image corresponds to an **entire ray** in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, as long as you do not know the distance of your measured points from the camera, you can't.

Imagine the image as a plane between the focus point of the camera and the objects you want to capture. When light is coming from an object (red points) to the focus point, they intersect the image plane. That intersection point is the location of the object on the image.

As you can see, objects that are further away from the camera appear closer together on the image plane.
In this sketch, the close points have the same pixel distance as the far away points.
So unless you know the distance between each point you want to measure and the camera, you cannot calculate the distance between these points from one image.

[image]

Comment: There are at least two methods to know the distance of measured points (a) "time of flight" which is a special camera and (b) stereo which uses multiple images of the same scene from different angles.  OP's question sounds like stereo (with vertical separation rather than horizontal).

Comment: @BenVoigt Both of those options give you the distance from the camera, which is what I was referring to in the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, and I was pointing out that the OP is describing a pair of images, which makes depth estimation via stereo techniques possible even though "distance from the camera" is not part of the data reported from the camera.